# $\alpha$ is on $[0,1]$ and $\alpha(1/2)=1$ and 0 elsewhere,f is continuous funtion. What shall I surprise about the Stieltjes integral $\int fd\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The question is as follows:

> Define $\alpha$ on the unit interval $[0, 1]$ by $\alpha(1/2)=1$ and 0 elsewhere. Compute $\int fd\alpha$ for an arbitrary continuous function $f$ on the unit interval. Are you surprised?

I tried as follow:

$\forall \varepsilon>0$,choose $\delta>0$ which satisfies $|\int fd\alpha - S_\alpha(f,P)|<\varepsilon$ whenever the partition $P \in \mathcal{P}_\delta$

then I choose a $P \in \mathcal{P}_\delta$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ in it, and suppose that the point before and after $\frac{1}{2}$ is $s_0$ and $s_1$.
If for the two intervals:$[s_0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and $[\frac{1}{2},s_1]$ I both choose $\frac{1}{2}$ the representative.Then $S_\alpha(f,P)=f(\frac{1}{2})(\alpha(\frac{1}{2})-\alpha(s_0)+\alpha(s_1)-\alpha(\frac{1}{2}))=0$.

Then $|\int fd\alpha - 0| < |\int fd\alpha - S_\alpha(f,P)| + |S_\alpha(f,P)-0| = \epsilon$, which claims that the integral I wanted is 0.

I'm wondering whether I get the answer right or not……, and what should I be surprised about ? Any help and hints will be appreciated!

Best regards!

p.s. : I have another thought, can I recognize this $\alpha$ as a delta function and use the integration by parts method in the Riemann integral?(I know this is not precise)

Comment: I agree with your result, and the only way I would expect people to be surprised is if they *thought* this was the Dirac delta "measure/function" (like the answer below), but that's not how Stieltjes integrals work. So I've put a comment on the answer below raising that issue - perhaps I've missed something too, and the discussion around that should clarify things.